# Django suppresses exceptions?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Been stuck with hard to find misbehavior. After many hours revealed it looks like Django suppresses `AttributeError` and possibly other exceptions:

```
from django import forms

class MyBaseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('field1', 'field2', )
    …

class MyForm(MyBaseForm):
    def clean_field1(self):
        super(MyForm, self).clean_field1()   # calling non-exitsting method
        # instead of AttributeError exception being raised,
        # following code is not executed without a warning
        return self.another_field_handler('field1')
```

Can anybody explain if this surprising behavior is normal for Django forms ? Some link where is it documented?

Comment: Except it doesn't catch any `AttributeError`. Either `clean_field1()` is not called, or `super().clean_field1` exists.

Comment: @knbk If I wrap `super(MyForm, self).clean_field1()` with try/except, the `AttributeError` exception is catched and following code gets executed. If the exception is not handled, like in the question, it won't propagate and is silently ignored.

Comment: No, that does not happen. If you call `MyForm().clean_field1()`, you *will* get an AttributeError.

Comment: @DanielRoseman `MyForm().clean_field1()` does raise AttributeError, but it is swallowed somewhere in the stack - no info about exception in logs, next view is correctly rendered. Django running with `DEBUG=True` setting. How can I figure out where is the exception silenced ?

Comment: You'll need to show the actual view as evidence that this is happening. There is no code in any of the form classes to silence errors like this.

Comment: Somewhere in the stack can be the view or the middleware. Are you using any custom/third-party middleware?

Comment: Form is a subclass of [CallbackUUIDOrderForm](https://github.com/explodes/cartridge-payments/blob/master/payments/multipayments/forms/base.py#L12), view with the form passed as argument is [checkout_steps](https://bitbucket.org/stephenmcd/cartridge/src/e2d8d032dee5051fc06df17d635808f51ca847a6/cartridge/shop/views.py?at=default#cl-207)

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in the view, but the project contains lot of middleware processors. Some good practice how track the silenced exception or do I have to manually look into each one ?